# Connect and view the screen of a raspberry pi connected via ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, vnc

This may be a complicated situation, but...

I have a raspberry pi elsewhere in the world.
I only have access to it via ssh directly to its public ip.

Host (Windows) -> Guest (Raspberry Pi)

I CANNOT enable port-forwarding due to this, so TightVNC is out of the question.

I tried using NoMachine, but no luck, I'd always get "cannot connect to the requested display" and it would not work.

When it did stop spitting errors, I still couldn't connect.

Are there any other (free) alternatives that can be started from ssh and don't require port forwarding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention TightVNC, and you can totally use VNC if you have access via SSH. Assuming that you have a running VNC server on the Rpi, then you will "ssh -L 5900:localhost:5900" for example to map from your local machine to the SSH session then just VNC to localhost.

Here is an example using Putty as the client, but you can also just use CMD in Windows or TERM in linux.

[How to Tunnel VNC over SSH](https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/tunnel-vnc-over-ssh/)